# Remove one value from all drop down using jquery

Tags: javascript, php

I have multiple drop down with same value.If they select Lunch first time from other drop down I have to remove Lunch. Following is my code

Front end code

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<=7; $i++) 
{?>
<select name="task<?php echo $i;?>" onchange="checkSelected(this,<?php echo $i; ?>);" id="task<?php echo $i;?>"
  <option value="Testing">Testing</option>
  <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

In javascript I am removing 3rd select box (task3) its got removed but i have to remove all the other except the selected one how i can implement this

javascript function

```
function checkSelected(e,number)
 {
   if(e.value == 'Lunch')
   {
        $('#task3 option[value="Lunch"]').remove();


   }

 }
```

I tried this but its not working

```
 $("#task+"number"+ > option[value='Lunch']").remove();
```

Comment: First error: the + signs. The line $("#task+"number"+ > option[value='Lunch']").remove(); have to be $("#task" + number + " > option[value='Lunch']").remove();

Comment: could you create a fiddle for better understanding of your question ?

Comment: The remove action only concern "lunch" or all available values "testing", eso?

Comment: it should remove only lunch

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$("#task" + number + " > option[value='Lunch']").remove();
```

Comment: Not too difficult to use my comment?

Comment: @NicolasHenrard why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: its removing from selected drop down

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.each()` function to remove only the option that has the value you select from the list.

```
$('select').change(function(){

    var value = $(this).val()
    // Probably best to store this value here before removing the option below.

    $(this).children().each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == value){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });

});
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/amQuU/

Example with multiple dropdowns http://jsfiddle.net/amQuU/1/

Example that removes the options from another select box - http://jsfiddle.net/amQuU/2/

The only problem in doing this is that by removing the selected option it is not shown as the selected option. you can however store the value after selecting it and before removing it from the list as commented above.

Another thing you should consider is changing `.remove()` to `.attr('disabled','true')` so that you can re-enable the option later on if you need to e.g. someone wants to go back and change the previous select. Here is an example of that too http://jsfiddle.net/amQuU/3/

Comment: the OP will use dynamic names for the select element. giving it a static name will never achieve what he wants

Answer (score 0):

If only the "lunch" option is concerned by your answer (see my comment above), then there's a solution. It's not already full-optimized, but you see how you can do it.

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/4qndV/1/

**HTML**

```
<form action="demo.html" id="myForm">
    <p>
        <label>First:</label>
        <select class="event_handler" name="task1">
            <option value="Testing">Testing</option>
            <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Second:</label>
        <select class="event_handler" name="task2">
            <option value="Testing">Testing</option>
            <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $(".event_handler").on("change", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var name_select = $(this).attr("name");

        if ($(this).val() == "Lunch") {
            //Loop through each "lunch" element
            $('.event_handler option[value=Lunch]').each(function(){
                //Remove all 'lunch' option, except the ont in the 'name_select' select
                if($(this).parent().attr("name") != name_select){
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

NB: I suppose you have to allow the user to change his selection. It's why I use "disable" in place of "remove". But you can easily adapt this code if you really want to remove the option element.

Comment: I think you haven't understand what i asked

Comment: if he select first option as lunch from other select box i have to remove lunch . So that ther is no option for lunch for nxt time

Comment: but still its not  removing lunch from drop down

Comment: You want to remove lunch for all dropdown?

Comment: yes only the select drop down should contain lunch rest of other drop down should not contain lunch

Comment: but tis is for multiple drop down

Comment: if i select one from first box one should remove from another box not the same box

Comment: You could do that by just changing the selector I have added `.siblings('select')` so that it changes the select box next to it. http://jsfiddle.net/amQuU/2/

Comment: this is not the sibling